# how to connect jconsole portal with appservers

Tags: memory, jboss, jconsole

I m  using jboss  app server in my office. Now  i am getting cpu load issues often.  I am using nagios as a monitoring tool and  we face the issue that  cpu usage often grows and we not able to find  the solution for this . 
After the long research we found the jconsole  is the  solution for this issue . Using the jconsole we are able to manage with the  Heap and non heap memory...

Now all i need is to find how do i connect  my app server instances with the jconsole so that i m  able to  do a "Manual GC (Garbage collction)". Can anybody help me out to reduce my tension please. And can anybody tell me how the jconsole works with the appservers.

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html?